# Fees on stock market calculation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stock

i am working on a backtest and I had a problem with the fee calculation.

Supose the fee is 0.1%

And I have already the buy/sell prices so I can retrieve the percentage of profit:

where:

```
df['Profit'] = ((df['Sells'] - df['Buys']) / df['Buys']) + 1
```

Example:

| Buys | Sells | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3697.35 | 3698.69 | 1.000362 |
| 3698.24 | 3699.81 | 1.000425 |
| 3703.69 | 3706.23 | 1.000686 |

So the returns without the fees are

```
returns = df.Profit.cumprod()
```

How can I calculate the actual return (with the fees) ?

Comment: What does a "fee of 0.1%" mean? Is it a fee on each transaction? Or on the profits?

Comment: @TCArlen , is 0.1% on each transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your formula first:

```
Profit = (Sells - Buys) / Buys + 1
       = Sells / Buys - Buys / Buys + 1
       = Sells / Buys - 1           + 1
       = Sells / Buys
```

Now due to the transaction fee, 0.1% is deducted from your Sells and also added to your Buys. We can thus rewrite the code as:

```py
fee = 0.001
df['Profit'] = df['Sells'].mul(1 - fee) / df['Buys'].mul(1 + fee)
```